# Should we be more worried about [corrosion]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just came across [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/71269/11367) on the main page, and noticed that we haven't specifically been paying attention to [corrosion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corrosion) on the site.

I'm concerned that we may be overlooking a major maintenance problem. On a quick look around, I found [**one hundred fifty-nine**](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=corro*%20is%3Aquestion) spots of [corrosion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corrosion).

Should we mark these somehow, so that we can find them more easily?

Comment: [160 now](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/71312/corrosion-rate-increases-with-salt-concentration), although hardly the best question... I think it's not a bad idea. If you could write up a tag wiki too, that would be great. If somebody knowledgeable enough to write a proper wiki is on the job, that seems (to me) to be a good indicator that the tag is reasonable to have.

Comment: @orthocresol I'll gladly take on the tag wiki. Should I give it a couple more days, to give more of the community a chance to see it and weigh in?

Comment: Yup, sure! Site seems to be moving slightly slowly these few days. Take your time.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see anything wrong with creating this tag as it seems to already have the critical mass to be used appropriately. I also think that the [MATT](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2968/4945) is good for this one (I got 18).

Moreover it will give us a chance to review the questions and maybe sort out a few not so good ones. While editing, keep in mind not to flush the homepage with 150 odd questions at once.

It would be very much appreciated, that you write a tag usage and a short entry into the wiki, if you choose to create the tag.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'd do a search for untagged, related questions (maybe put together a SEDE query, if needed -- am hooked now) and go through maybe 10-15 questions a day, 9-11pm EDT (2-4amUTC, I think?).

Comment: @hBy2Py maybe add it to the github project?

Comment: @heather <nod>, once I get the tag wiki and excerpt drafted, I'll figure out a good search breakdown and create a Project for it. Focus for now remains [reaction].