# System auto identifying a post as spam

Tags: support

> [image]

Is there any reasoning to see this message in the close review queue? When does this happen?

Comment: There is nothing in the timeline to suggest as much https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/168693/timeline It might be due to other account activity by the user. If it doesn't look like spam I would just ignore the message.

Comment: @BuckThorn Still looks strange, the user has a total of 2 questions with a -3 vote tally so far.

Comment: Might be related: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5126/community-bot-aggresive-closing-of-spam-abusing-false-positives

Comment: I'll wait for the other mods to weigh in on this. If it is a human-made decision, that is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

appears because at the time of posting user [Malek](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/128185/malek) shared the IP address with an offender account who recently posted spam or made an offensive post.
Simply put, it's a request from the spam filter algorithm to pay additional attention when reviewing the given post because of the risk of possible spam recidivism from the jailbird account.

The same IP could be due to the use of shared university network or same VPN provider and happens quite often, hence a need for careful review on a different basis.
Mods are not allowed to leak user's IP addresses.
The most I can say is that an unregistered user posted nonsensical homework request in a demanding and illiterate manner and their question has been flagged as *inappropriate for respectful discourse*.

As for [Is calcium carbonate a Brønsted–Lowry base, a Lewis base, or both?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/168693), I edited the question a bit (which I wouldn't do if there were signs of spam) and it has been answered.
It looks like this time we all can breathe a sigh of relief and move on.

#### Further reading

1. SO blog: [How does spam protection work on Stack Exchange?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/)
2. SO Meta: [Why am I getting "Our system has identified this post as possible spam" in review audits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267355)
3. Math.SE Meta: ["Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12597/our-system-has-identified-this-post-as-possible-spam-please-review-carefully)

Comment: I think if there is an actual spam flag on the post (for whatever reason), the message appears, too.