# Why is my question not submissible?

Tags: support

I've written a question for Chemistry SE but get "Your question couldn’t be submitted Resolve 1 issue before posting". This is the title which I've reworded a number of times without meeting tje hidden/unknowable requirements and is currently "What might stop bismuth crystals from being iridescent?" which seems like a perfectly valid question to me.
What am I, or SE, doing wrong?

Comment: From what I see, you don't have any blocks or limitations on Chemistry.SE. Could you please provide us with more info? A full-screen screenshot may be helpful; also, feel free to add the new question body to this question alongside with the exact set of chosen tags and the title. There is a small chance it might be caused by software issues, so feel free to add some info about your OS and browser (have you tried submission with all addons disabled/cookies cleaned?) as well.

Comment: I've somehow managed to remove the block, but now can't post it as I posted here and I have to wait 40 minutes. I find SE so frustrating for many reasons and avoid coming here or the trauma of the previous visit has faded.  I *think* it didn't like my tag "bismuth" even though that's not obviously the title - the tag input field being after the content doesn't intuitively suggest it's part of the title.  I did a number of things so can't be certain what it was that made it ok.

Comment: @user3418765 Before posting your question, please go through [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32484/what-causes-the-iridescent-colour-in-laboratory-grown-bismuth). Tl:DR: scraping of the bismuth(III) oxide layer or contamination might prevent bismuth from getting iridescent.

Answer (score 8):

To wrap the comments up, [you commented](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5016/why-is-my-question-not-submissible#comment11161_5016)

> I *think* it didn't like my tag "bismuth"

and this tag issue was the reason.
The system were declining your question because you were trying to [create a new tag without having 300 rep points](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

In the future, please refrain from creating tags for the chemical elements: these are useless because you can find all relevant posts simply by searching for this element's name.
Introducing new tag also should ideally begin from asking whether it is reasonable on this Meta, and if you don't have enough reputation, proposing a new tag by creating a request by starting a new discussion on Meta is the only way.
A well-written summary can be found on SO: [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Honourable mention of our guide: [What do I need to know about tagging?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2967/4945)